# Using an instrumental variable in a logit regression on an imputed data set

Tags: r, statistics, r-zelig

I have imputed missing value using the Amelia package. I am now analysing the data using regressions.

I have been using the following code

```
require(Zelig)
z.out <- zelig(catastrophic ~ age + PC1 + sex + hh_size + wealth_quin + 
hh_exp_quin, model="logit", data = a.output$imputation)
summary(z.out)
```

Where a.output is an imputed data set. (I still need to code the combining of the multiple imputed data sets, but know how to do that, so that comes later).

I have found that my model has quite a lot of endogeneity between hh_exp_quin and the dependent variable (which is a binary variable, hence the model is "logit").

As such, I want to use another variable (not currently included in this model, call it "var1") as an instrumental variable for hh_exp_quin.

the zelig package doesn't currently seem to support "ivreg", and I can't find anything online telling me how to deal with this.

Many thanks,

Timothy

Answer (score 0):

Try the ivreg command in the package AER.

Comment: But from what I can see, AER can't deal with imputed data sets?

Comment: Recommendations for a package are supposed to be in comments not answers. Having said that, you impute your data before using ivreg or any function and there's nothing special for the function to support.